# How to connect to a MySQL server via a SOCKS or HTTP proxy?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

The reason I want to do is to connect to a firewalled MySQL server from a PAAS, Heroku, which can't give me a static IP out of the box. I am using PHP 7 with the Symfony framework. I am aware a possibility might be to create a SSH tunnel, but I am afraid that adds too much complexity and overhead.

Comment: AutoSSH makes tunneling situations like this much more manageable: http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/